# Crystal Reports 11: Adding PNG to OLE Object

Tags: crystal-reports, png, png-transparency

I'm trying to add a PNG-image, with transparency to an OLE Object in my Crystel Reports 11, report.

When I run the report, the image just turns black.

Is there a way to solve this, or does Crystal Reports not support PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CR does support PNG (along with BMP, TIFF, JPEG, and WMF), but does *not* officially support transparency. That's not to say there aren't workarounds, though.

One option is to convert the overlay image to WMF, insert it into the report, and then position the image over top of whatever other image you may have (via the "Move to front" option on the right-click menu). Details are here: [Add an image with transparency to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847204/add-an-image-with-transparency-to-crystal-reports)