# Does CR report Image Transparency?

Tags: image, crystal-reports, report, transparency

I'd like to insert an image on crystal report that has  transparency.  However in CR the transparent portions show up as white and cover over whatever color is behind the image.
I hunted about for setting on the image format but cant find one.  Does anyone have an idea I might try?

Comment: try making the image transparent using online tools and then insert the image in crystal reports.

Comment: when I change to transparent image and then insert into CR but the background still appear (can't be transparent) .

Comment: try this : [Add an image with transparency to Crystal Reports][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847204/add-an-image-with-transparency-to-crystal-reports

Comment: i have try your solution @anrijunuka but it's not work and background still appear.