# Covering Background Color in Crystal-Report went Adding Watermark

Tags: crystal-reports, watermark

Why when adding a pic for watermark, always cover the detail background color?
I have tried with another type file. But it still same result. Anyone can help me?
[Crystal-Report with example watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF6om.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847204/add-an-image-with-transparency-to-crystal-reports

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports doesn't have very good support for the transparent layer background of most image file formats.  In almost all cases, images files are converted to a Bitmap image when they are used in a Crystal Report.  This causes images to have a background that is slightly off compared to the color of the reports background.  Underlay and moving the image behind other objects on the report help with most issues for the report's design, but you can never place the image behind the background.

There is a workaround for this using WMF or EMF files though.  These are two image file formats that work in Crystal Report and support transparent layer backgrounds.  If you don't have photo editing software that can produce WMF or EMF file, then there are two ways to do this without buying additional software.  The first option is MS PowerPoint.  If you insert the image into a PowerPoint presentation, then right click the inserted image, you can then choose Save As Picture and WMF and EMF are both available file types for this.  The second option is a website called [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com).  This website will allow you to convert files from one file type to another.  Its a fairly fast service, but they have file size limits for free users.

Always keep in mind that the image will need to have a transparent background in the original file format before converting it to a WMF or EMF file.  Also bear in mind that converting files from one type to another can sometimes have unintended implications upon the quality and detail of the images.  Sometimes the best way to get a good quality image is to seek out the graphic designer who produced the image and request they provide the image in the WMF or EMF file types.